# Return Error .subscribe Angular5

Tags: angular

I want send return Error when my function fails, but I don't know how I do...

Service.ts

```
 math(){
     try {
             .
             .
             .
       } catch (error) {
          return "error";
      }
    }

calc(url){
  num  = math();
  if (num !== "error"){
    return this.http.get<Object[]>(url);
  } else {
      return Error;
  }
}
```

component.ts

```
  this.service.calc(url).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.params = data;
            }, error => {
                this.errorServer = true;
                this.myMessage.message = "Error";
            }
        );
```

I get error in `this.service.calc(url).subscribe` because this doesn't allow ->  `Return Error` from calc

Comment: Could you post a Stackblitz/ paste the full code of your `math` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `throwError`  for return observable.

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

calc(url){
  num  = math();
  if (num !== "error"){
    return this.http.get<Object[]>(url);
  } else {
      return throwError('Error');
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `throwError` instead of `of`. So the subscriber knows it's an error.